# write a query in sql

Tags: sql-server-2005, join

I have two tables that have following rows:

Table1

```
ID  Name Number 
===================== 
1    a    100 
2    b    200 
3    c    300
```

Table2

```
ID Number Check
=====================
1   100     0
2   200     1
3   300    null
```

Now I want the following table:

```
table
---------------------
Name Number check
=====================
a     100    0
c     300   null
```

What query I must to write.

*You notice that the column of check in the row of 'c' in final table is **null**.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the condition why there's no row with name b and Number 200 in the result? In general you're looking for a LEFT JOIN  it seems

Comment: Hint: Use the code snippet button `{}` to indent your tables by at least four spaces in order to have them appear in a monospace font.

Comment: Edit number 8 to this question was probably a mistake. It removed the reason to use a `left outer join` which probably was what the OP really needed to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Left outer join** is your friend:

```
select table1.name, table1.nmber, table2.check from table1 left outer join table2 on table1.nmber = table2.number
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the nmber column in table1 = number column in table2

```
 SELECT a.name, a.nmber, b.check
 FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.nmber = b.number
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your looking for

```
select a.Name, a.Nmber, b.Check
from Table1 a join table2 b
on a.Nmber = b.Number
```

can also add a where clase e.g.

```
where a.Name is not b
where b.check is not 1
```

etc

Hard to tell from your question how you want your results to exclude b

Answer (score 0):

Set up test data.

```
create table table1(ID int, Name char(1), Number int)
create table table2(ID int, Number int, [Check] int)

insert into table1 values (1, 'a', 100)
insert into table1 values (2, 'b', 200)
insert into table1 values (3, 'c', 300)

insert into table2 values (1, 100, 0)
insert into table2 values (2, 200, 1)
insert into table2 values (3, 300, null)
```

The query

```
select
    table1.Name,
    table1.Number,
    table2.[Check]
from table1
    inner join table2
        on table1.ID = table2.ID
where Name <> 'b'
```

Result

```
a   100 0
c   300 NULL
```

You must use square brackets around column name `[check]` because check is a reserved word. in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been edited a lot. I believe that the answer to the original question differ from the answer to the current question.

Here is the setup for version 1 one of the question.

```
create table table1(ID int, Name char(1), Number int)
create table table2(ID int, Number int, [Check] int)

insert into table1 values (1, 'a', 100)
insert into table1 values (2, 'b', 200)
insert into table1 values (3, 'c', 300)

insert into table2 values (1, 100, 0)
insert into table2 values (2, 200, 1)
```

To get c from table1 when joined to table2 you need to use a left outer join.

```
select
    table1.Name,
    table1.Number,
    table2.[Check]
from table1
    left outer join table2
        on table1.ID = table2.ID
where table1.Name <> 'b'
```

Even in this version you need the square brackets around check.